# Getting a null when trying to query data from different models - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a model `transaction` and it has a column `transaction_id`. This transaction id can be connected to different other models using their respective `_ids`.

But how does it know this id is from `transfer` model or `deposit` model?. The transaction model has another column called `type`, which can either be `transfer` or `deposit` And this is how it'll know the model being referenced is either deposit or transfer or withdrawal.

So I have tried to create an api route to return the transaction details with the respective connected model details. The problem is, I am getting a null value on the `transaction_id`. Someone kindly help

```
router.get("/transactions", isAuth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const transactions = await Transaction.find({
      user_id: req.user.id,
    }).populate({
      path: "transaction_id",
      model: req.body.type == "transfer" ? Transfer : Deposit,
    });
    

    if (!transactions) {
      return res.status(400).send({ error: "Transactions not found" });
    }

    res.json({ success: true, transactions });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: error.message });

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the problem is with the req.body.type in the model property of the populate function. To get the value from the request body, you should use req.query.type instead of req.body.type as the GET request does not have a request body. try this-

```
router.get("/transactions", isAuth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const transactions = await Transaction.find({
      user_id: req.user.id,
    }).populate({
      path: "transaction_id",
      model: req.query.type === "transfer" ? Transfer : Deposit,
    });
    

    if (!transactions) {
      return res.status(400).send({ error: "Transactions not found" });
    }

    res.json({ success: true, transactions });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: error.message });

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it still doesn't work